# Validate select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm validating a form, but I'm having problems with this particular select validation.

```
<div class="control-group" id="sukupuoli">
        <label class="control-label">Sukupuoli</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="sukupuoli">
            <option value="Valitse">Valitse</option>
            <option value="Naaras">Naaras</option>
            <option value="Uros">Uros</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS for the validation:

```
$('#ilmoittuminen').submit(function(){

        var Sukupuoli = $('input[name=sukupuoli]').val()

            if(Sukupuoli  == "Valitse"){
            $('.control-group#sukupuoli').addClass("error");
            $('select[name=sukupuoli]').focus();
            return false; 
            }

            var ilmoittautumisdata = $('#ilmoittuminen').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "",
                data: ilmoittautumisdata,
                type: "POST"})
            .done(function () {

                })
            .error(function () {
            $('.control-group').addClass("alert");
            });

                return false;
});
```

It doesn't submit, but it doesn't add the class error either. [A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianNikkanen/HV7sn/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `select` here:

```
var Sukupuoli = $('select[name=sukupuoli]').val()
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/HV7sn/1/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use $('.control-group#sukupuoli').addClass("error"); just select it by the id only:

$('#sukupuoli').addClass("error");

Comment: It's for if I have a dublicate id for somereason.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen It is not good practice to have any duplicate id for any reason. Id should be unique in any aspect of programming related subject.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Well, and humans able to fix their errors, so fix it!

Comment: It's not an error, it's a backdoor for the script, if I manage to create an error.